# node.js ,async and if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, mongoose

this code below return messages "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

why?? my English is bad . so let me write in Japanese. sorry.

パラメータで送られた値を２種類の配列に変えて、それぞれの値をキーにmongodbから削除しようと以下のコードを書いたんですが、上のメッセージがでてきてうまくいきません。
送られたパスワードが違ったらエラーページへ飛ばしてうまくいったら、res.redirect('back')で元の画面に戻したいのですが、よいアドバイスがありましたらご教授お願いします。

```
app.post('/thread/remove', function(req, res, next) {
var deletethread = req.param('deletethread'),
  deletepost = req.param("delete_post"),
  localpassword = req.param('localpassword'),
  category_id = req.param('category_id'),
  arraydeletethread = String(deletethread).split(","),
  arraydeletepost = String(deletepost).split(","),
  error_flag = false;

  console.log("arraydeletethread = " + arraydeletethread + ", arraydeletethread.length = " + arraydeletethread.length);
   if (deletethread) {
if(arraydeletethread.length > 0) {
  async.forEachSeries(arraydeletethread, function(val, callback) {
    if (val) {
      ThreadModel.findOne({post_id: Number(val)}, function(err, threadResult) {
        if(err) {
          console.log('error');
          return next(err);
        }
        if (threadResult.password !== localpassword) {
          error_flag = true;
          req.flash('errors', 'wrong password');
          req.flash('category_id', category_id);
          return res.redirect("/post/error");
        } else {
          threadResult.remove();
          console.log('remove suceeded!');
        }
      });
    }
  }, function() {
    console.log('thread remove finished!');
  });
}
  }

  console.log("arraydeletepost = " + arraydeletepost + ", arraydeletepost.length = " +   arraydeletepost.length);
  if (deletepost) {
if(arraydeletepost.length > 0){
  async.forEachSeries(arraydeletepost, function(val, callback) {
    if (val) {
      var arraydeletepost_i = String(val).split("_");
      ThreadModel.findOne({'replies.post_id': Number(arraydeletepost_i[1]), "post_id": Number(arraydeletepost_i[0])}, function(err, replyResult){
        if(err) {
          console.log('error');
          return next(err);
        }
        if (replyResult.password !== localpassword) {
          error_flag = true;
          req.flash('errors', 'wrong password');
          req.flash('category_id', category_id);
          return res.redirect("/post/error");
        } else {
          ThreadModel.update({post_id: Number(arraydeletepost_i[0])},{$pull: {replies: {post_id: Number(arraydeletepost_i[1])}}}, function(err){
            if(err) {
              console.log('error');
              return next(err);
            }
            console.log('remove suceeded!');
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }, function() {
    console.log('post remove finished!');
  });
}
  }
  return res.redirect('back');
});
```

---

I changed my code like this. and error case went well, but the process is no longer come back and does not return to the previous screen after it was removed from the mongodb normal system. (google translated)
エラーケースはうまくいきましたが、正常系はmongodbから削除できたあとに前の画面に戻らず処理が帰ってこなくなりました...

```
app.post('/thread/remove', function(req, res, next) {
var deletethread = req.param('deletethread'),
  deletepost = req.param("delete_post"),
  localpassword = req.param('localpassword'),
  category_id = req.param('category_id'),
  arraydeletethread = String(deletethread).split(","),
  arraydeletepost = String(deletepost).split(",");

console.log("arraydeletethread = " + arraydeletethread + ", arraydeletethread.length = " + arraydeletethread.length);
console.log("arraydeletepost = " + arraydeletepost + ", arraydeletepost.length = " +   arraydeletepost.length);

async.parallel([
  function(callback) {
    if (deletethread) {
      if(arraydeletethread.length > 0) {
        async.forEachSeries(arraydeletethread, function(val, callback) {
          if (val) {
            ThreadModel.findOne({post_id: Number(val)}, function(err, threadResult) {
              if(err) {
                console.log('error');
                return callback("err = " + err);
              } else {
                if (threadResult.password !== localpassword) {
                  console.log('wrong password error');
                  return callback(new Error("wrong password error"));
                } else {
                  threadResult.remove();
                  console.log('remove suceeded!');
                  callback();
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }, function() {
          console.log('forEach thread finished');
        });
      }
    }
  },
  function(callback) {
    if (deletepost) {
      if(arraydeletepost.length > 0){
        async.forEachSeries(arraydeletepost, function(val, callback) {
          if (val) {
            var arraydeletepost_i = String(val).split("_");
            ThreadModel.findOne({'replies.post_id': Number(arraydeletepost_i[1]), "post_id": Number(arraydeletepost_i[0])}, function(err, replyResult){
              if(err) {
                console.log('error');
                return callback(err);
              } else {
                if (replyResult.password !== localpassword) {
                  console.log('wrong password error');
                  return callback(new Error("wrong password error"));
                } else {
                  ThreadModel.update({post_id: Number(arraydeletepost_i[0])},{$pull: {replies: {post_id: Number(arraydeletepost_i[1])}}}, function(err){
                    if(err) {
                      console.log('error');
                      return callback(err);
                    } else {
                      console.log('remove suceeded!');
                      callback();
                    }
                  });
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }, function() {
          console.log('forEach post finished');
        });
      }
    }
  }
],function(err) {
  if (err) {
    if (err.message === 'wrong password error') {
      req.flash('errors', 'パスワードが違います。');
      req.flash('category_id', category_id);
      return res.redirect("/post/error");
    } else {
      return next(err);
    }
  } else {
    res.redirect('back');
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Which version of express are you using ? req.flash was removed from express 3.x

Comment: I think I am using latest version of express 3.x. and I installed connect-flash npm package. this helps me to use req.flash under express 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

There are structural errors in the code:

1. In the iterator function for `async.forEachSeries(arraydeletethread` the callback `next` is called - it will be called several times (because the iterator is executed for every item in the list), which is wrong. You need to call it only once. The same for `res.redirect`
2. async blocks for the `arraydeletethread` and `arraydeletepost` arrays should also be wrapped in `async.waterfall` or something. Then the `next` or `redirect` should be called in the final callback for this wrapping async statement, not earlier.

P.S. use google translate, it works quite well.

Comment: Thank you for polite advice Alex. I will try what you said.

Comment: I can review your code when you done the changes if you wish. See: http://alexatnet.com/projects/code-review-4u Cheers